# Essential Apps For SalesForce Non profit Starter pack

Tags: administration

What apps would be considered essential addons to the SalesForce Non Profit Starter Pack

Comment: Welcome! This is a bit open-ended and broad for SFSE where questions should be about a specifc problem. That said, I think it maybe of use so we'll see what answers come in and maybe make it into a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile so excuse brevity and/or typos but do check out crmfusion demandblocker at [this link](http://www.crmfusion.com/dupeblocker/dupeblocker-details/). Ive seen this used by NPOs (who can get it free or very cheap I believe) with great success to improve data quality.

Volunteerforce at [this link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cifEAA) is also worth a look if you need a volunteer management app ready to go rather than 'roll your own'.

Finally, there are some great little 'drip marketing' apps on appexchange that are free and assume you're working within the system imposed email limits. One of these may prove very helpful for small scale marketing campaign automation.